# How to deal with spaces in JSON Key?

Tags: json, parsing, groovy, jsonslurper

I have a string of JSON that I've retrieved from an API. I'm using `JsonSlurper` to parse the string into JSON, but I'm unsure how to handle when the key contains spaces.

An example of the JSON is:

```
{
   "total": 3,
   "page": 1,
   "totalPages": 1,
   "results": [{
      "person name": "John Doe",
      "date of birth": "01/01/1990",
      "date of registration": "01/01/2016",
      "notes": "default user",
    }]
 }
```

I want to iterate through the results that are returned and find a specific person by `person name`. The code I have so far, which I doubt will work is:

```
final RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def response = rest.get("http://example.com/api/getPeople")
def json = slurper.parseText(response.text)
def jsonResults = json.results
jsonResults.each { res ->
   assert res.personName == 'John Doe'
}
```

What is the correct way to get `"person name"` since it has spaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it with `'`:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input = '''{
   "total": 3,
   "page": 1,
   "totalPages": 1,
   "results": [{
      "person name": "John Doe",
      "date of birth": "01/01/1990",
      "date of registration": "01/01/2016",
      "notes": "default user",
   }]
}'''

def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

json.results.each { res ->
   assert res.'person name' == 'John Doe'
}
```